# Very Sexual 1960s SF Short Story/Novelette

Tags: story-identification

This story is most definitely a product of the late 1960s/70s because of its sexual nature. I am pretty sure it was in one of the American magazines of the period, although it might have been an anthology (*Dangerous Visions*, maybe?). The time is the near future. The hero is being chased by somebody and to avoid pursuit he ducks into a kind of sexual carnival. Although he does not partake, he witnesses the various entertainments. Two of them really impressed me: by entering one room it was possible to have sex with a ghost. The other was a game of chance called 'Stick-It' (honest!), where a male puts a particular organ into a hole in the wall and has either an incredible sexual experience or is castrated by a razor. To a teen who grew up reading *Analog* (don't bother looking for it there) it was a real eye-opener.

Comment: Probably too explicit for one of the mainstream magazines, but Dangerous Visions is a possibility. It had a certain willingness to go against the establishment. I have no idea about the story, but I would like to read it.

Comment: I read this one! It's in one of my short novels anthologies, but I have something like 50 tomes, and it would help a lot if you remembered the general "theme" of the story: other worlds/bleak future/human augmentation...?

Comment: It's the first tome I checked X) I skimmed through, and it did not seem to fit. I'll take more time later.

Comment: I'm sorry, but all I can add is that the story might have had a dystopian feel.

Comment: I am certain it was not one of the slick magazines

Comment: Did that involve women with multiple orifices called something like "pork-upines"?

Comment: For all that it's worth, I think I associated that story with Robert Sheckley's "Love, Incorporated", so they might have been in the same book.

Comment: Nothing in *Dangerous Visions* like that. Not sure about *Again...* though.

Comment: I don't remember any pork-upines. Sheckley's story dates from the 1950s, which seems way too early. On the other hand, it did appear in the Playboy SF&F anthology.

Comment: Might be part of _[Mallworld](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/445426.Mallworld)_, which is a fixup.

Comment: "[A Day in Mallworld](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?189685)" appeared in Asimov's in 1979.

Comment: 1979 is far too late. I'm almost sure the story dates no later than the early 70s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was ["I See a Man Sitting On a Chair, and the Chair is Biting His Leg"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53728)
by Harlan Ellison & Robert Sheckley. It appears in *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction* of January 1968. I saw it in the [*Partners in Wonder*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?25649) anthology.

The lead character is an algae (waterborne mold?) harvester.  The "goo", the mold he harvested, was processed to make all kinds of things.  Safety precautions absolutely required that he make no contact whatsoever with the "goo", but he got slightly careless one day, then didn't think it was enough to warrant decontamination.  Next day, he is absolutely hairless.

He's contracted a disease that is associated with the mold.  Only four or five other humans are known to have contracted it, and each of them had wildly different reactions.

It turns out that the mold is sentient.  And then things get weird..

Comment: Good find. Also appears in [La Grande Anthologie de la Science-Fiction: Histoires de Mirages](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoires_de_mirages). A compressed version of the story is here in french: [Je vois un homme assis dans un fauteuil, et le fauteuil lui mord la jambe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Je_vois_un_homme_assis_dans_un_fauteuil,_et_le_fauteuil_lui_mord_la_jambe)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It does have that in-your-face Ellison feel to it. I met him once at a bookstand in LA. I recognized him and he talked the owner into giving me a copy of 'Paingod and Other Stories' for free.

Comment: I had read that in a Sheckley anthology and never knew till now that it was co-written by Ellison, because for some reason Ellison wasn't credited in that edition, but that makes a whole lot of sense - it's definitely a bit more lurid than Sheckley's usual style.